# React-table onFetchData getting triggered twice

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I am using react-table in my project. Don't know why onFetchData method of react-table getting called twice.

I am setting defaultFiltered as,

```
     defaultFiltered={[
          {
            id: 'status',
            value: this.getFilterValue(),
          }
      ]}
```

and my OnFetchData method as follows:

`onFetchData = (props) => {
    this.request = this.getData(props);
  }`

The react-table part as follows:

```
<ReactTable
      manual
      minRows = {1}
      getTdProps={this.onRowClick}
      onFetchData={this.onFetchData}
      data={!loading ? comparison.results : []}
      sortable={true}
      defaultSorted={[{
        id: 'deviation',
        desc: true,
      }]}
      filterable={showfilter === 1}
      defaultFiltered={[{
        id: 'status',
        value: this.props.statusFilter,
      }]}
      showPagination = {true}
      pages={comparison.metadata.totalPages}
      showPageSizeOptions = {true}
      pageSizeOptions = {[10, 15, 20, 25, 50, 100]}
      defaultPageSize={10}
      columns={this.getColumns}
 />
```

Comment: Could you provide a code sample?

Comment: And the render method? (especially with ReactTable component part)

Comment: added. If I remove the detaultFiltered section, its working fine. :(

Comment: check which one state or prop property has changed right after the render

Answer (score 0):

My solution is:
declare a fetchData state:

```
const [fetchState, setFetchState] = useState(null);
```

perform a deep equal comparison to avoid multiple action call

```
onFetchData={useCallback(({ page: nextPage, pageSize, sorted }) => {
      const nextFetch = { page: nextPage, pageSize, sorted };
      const prevFetch = fetchState;

      if (!deepEqual(nextFetch, prevFetch)) {
        setFetchState(nextFetch);
        onFetchData(nextFetch);
      }
    }, [fetchState, setFetchState])}
```

For convenience I also post my deepEqual definition:

```
const deepEqual = (a, b) => JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(b);
```